# Show $P(A) = \int_A f$ is a probability function if $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} ,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f = 1$

Tags: probability

For each $A \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$, show $P(A) = \int_A f$ is a probability function if $$f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} ,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f = 1$$
The first and third axioms are easy but I fail to see what in the definition of $f$ guarantees that $P(A) \ge 0$ holds.

Comment: I think some information is missing about $f$

Comment: Seems clear that you need to assume that $f≥0$.

Comment: Right. I wouldn't be surprised if the teacher had missed that, his material has plenty of mistakes. Thanks.